# Is there a problem with my code editor, or with my inheritance code?

Tags: html, css

Within my navigation bar, I added a p element. As I set the nav font size to 18px, all the anchor elements and the p element became 22px. I expected this for the p element because earlier I set all p elements to 22px, but why did it affect the anchor links within the navigation bar? I inspected this with DevTools and for some reason, when I added the p element, every anchor element within the nav element became nested within a p element, even though I never coded that.
Here is my HTML code:

```css
p {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

nav {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <p>This is the navigation<p>
  <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
  <a href="#">Challenges</a>
  <a href="#">Flexbox</a>
  <a href="#">CSS Grid</a>
</nav>
```

Here is what DevTools shows:

```
<nav>
  <p>This is the navigation<p>
  <p>
    <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
    <a href="#">Challenges</a>
    <a href="#">Flexbox</a>
    <a href="#">CSS Grid</a>
  <p>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your p tag doesn't have a closing bracket. You need the second one to be </p>

Comment: You haven't closed your paragraph tag

Answer (score 2):

You need to close `<p>` with `</p>`. Since you didn't all its siblings are treated as children.

```css
p {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

nav {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <p>This is the navigation</p>
  <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
  <a href="#">Challenges</a>
  <a href="#">Flexbox</a>
  <a href="#">CSS Grid</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Do not post answers to problems caused by typo type issues, they should be called out in comments and flagged, as there is a specific close flag **Not reproducible or was caused by a typo**. These questions are typically downvoted, closed and deleted, as they are of no benefit to the community.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite funny. It sometime happens and you become frustrated. The `<p>` element is not a self closing element so you need to include a `</p>` to close the element.

```css
p {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

nav {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <p>This is the navigation</p>
  <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
  <a href="#">Challenges</a>
  <a href="#">Flexbox</a>
  <a href="#">CSS Grid</a>
</nav>
```

This is gonna be the result for your code.

Comment: Well, you can use `<p>` without the closing tag, only it's bad practice.

Comment: You can use it but it affects the rest of the siblings if there are any. As long as there is one child in a parent, its not a  problem.

Comment: Do not post answers to problems caused by typo type issues, they should be called out in comments and flagged, as there is a specific close flag **Not reproducible or was caused by a typo**. These questions are typically downvoted, closed and deleted, as they are of no benefit to the community.